# Linear Programming with cvxpy

Tags: python, math, linear-programming, cvxpy, cvxopt

I would like to ask you regarding on the Linear Program for optimization.

I have an objective function, and constraint functions as below,

- variables(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6) are quantities of the products, and the quantities of products have to be fixed numbers now.
- the goal of this problem is the optimizing the quantities of products.

  1. Objective Function  (c.T * [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6])

     ```
     [[c11, c12, c13, c14, c15 c16],

     [c21, c22, c23, c24, c25, c26],
                                   X     [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6]  
     [c31, c32, c33, c34, c35, c36],

     [c41, c42, c43, c44, c45, c45]]
     ```

  The result that I would like to optimize is going to be as below

  ```
  c11*x1 + c12*x2 + c13*x3 + c14*x4 + c15*x5 + c16*x6 +
  c21*x1 + c22*x2 + c23*x3 + c24*x4 + c25*x5 + c26*x6 + 
  c31*x1 + c32*x2 + c33*x3 + c34*x4 + c35*x5 + c36*x6 + 
  c41*x1 + c42*x2 + c43*x3 + c44*x4 + c45*x5 + c46*x6 = optimized value
  ```

  2. Constraint Function

  1) constraint_1

  5500000*x1+2500000*x2+825000*x3+5500000*x4+5500000*x5+5500000*x6 <= 800000000

  2) constraint_2

  ```
  x1 <= 10
  x2 <= 10
  x3 <= 10
  x4 <= 10
  x5 <= 10
  x6 <= 10
  ```

The problem that I am suffering from is the in the "Objective Function of Cs(c1,1 ~ c4,5)".

I have solved the Linear Programming that has integers values in the Objective Functions, but not the matrix.

I have tried all other ways that I could, but now I really need helps on this.

Please kindly suggest me any kind of ideas or codes for this question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where exactly you see a problem. If I define `Ki` as `c1i+c2i+c3i+c4i`, then your problem becomes maximizing `K1*x1 + K2*x2 + ... + K6*x6` and you claim that you know how to solve that kind of problems. So where is the roadblock for you?

Comment: If an objective function is like 3 * x1 + 2 * x2 + 3 * x3 + 4 * x4 + 5 * x5 + 6 * x6, then the code will be as below,

Comment: `c = np.array([3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])`

`A = np.array([[5500000, 2500000, 825000, 5500000, 5500000, 5500000], [1,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0,0,1]])`

`b = np.array([800000000, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])`

`c = matrix(c, tc='d')` 
`G = matrix(A, tc='d')`
`h = matrix(b, tc='d')`

`status, x = glpk.ilp(c, g, h, I=set([0,1,2,3,4,5]))`

Comment: The problem that I am having is I am not sure how to extend the `c` parts. In the code, it is the 1 x 6 matrix, but now I need solve with the 4 x 6 matrix(c11 to c46).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have store the original cij in a numpy array, you might like to sum up terms like c11+c21+c31+c41 first. This can be done by summing up each column, try c.sum(axis = 0)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> c = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
>>> c
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
>>> c = c.sum(axis=0)
>>> c
array([36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56])
```